# Swap items in a sequence

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I am trying to write a heap sort algorithm using XSLT .But struggling to swap the values of the variable used for storing the tokenized values. I have created method heapify for comparing the values and swap the larger value to the current index. Anyone please help direct me to swap the values of the parent list.

```
<xsl:template match="/">

      <xsl:variable name="tokenizedSample" select="tokenize(.,' ')">             
    </xsl:variable>
    <!--<xsl:value-of select="."/>-->
    <xsl:call-template name="BuildHeap">
      <xsl:with-param name="intList" select="$tokenizedSample"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>



  <xsl:template name="BuildHeap">
   <xsl:param name="intList"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="$intList">
        <xsl:call-template name="Heapify">
          <xsl:with-param name="newintList" select="$intList"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="index"  select="position()"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>



  <xsl:template name="Heapify">    
    <xsl:param name="newintList"/>
    <xsl:param name="index"/>
    <xsl:variable name="stringval">
      <xsl:text></xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="vIndex">
      <xsl:number value="$index" />
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="stringval" select="concat(($stringval),'is')"/>
    <xsl:if test="$newintList[$vIndex*2] &gt; $newintList[$vIndex*1]  and $newintList[$vIndex*2] &gt; $newintList[($vIndex*2)+1] ">

    <!—swap the values of ith position with 2ith position-->

      <xsl:for-each select="$newintList">
        <xsl:if test="position()=$vIndex">
          <xsl:value-of select="$newintList[$vIndex*2]"/>
          <xsl:value-of select="$stringval"/>
          <xsl:variable name="stringval" select="concat(($stringval),'is',$newintList[$vIndex*2])"/>
          <xsl:value-of select="$stringval"/>
        </xsl:if>

        <xsl:if test="position()=($vIndex*2)">
          <xsl:value-of select="$stringval"/>
          <xsl:variable name="stringval" select="concat(($stringval),'is')"/>
          <xsl:value-of select="$stringval"/>
          <xsl:variable name="stringval" select="concat(($stringval),'is',$newintList[$vIndex*1])"/>
        </xsl:if>

      </xsl:for-each>

<xsl:value-of select="$stringval"/>
    </xsl:if>


    <xsl:if test="$newintList[($vIndex*2)+1] &gt; $newintList[$vIndex*1]  and $newintList[($vIndex*2)+1] &gt; $newintList[$vIndex*2] ">
    <!—swap the values of ith position with 2i+1th position-->

    </xsl:if>

  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: The `tokenize()` standard XPath 2.0 function is only available in XSLT 2.0. Are you sure you want an XSLT 1.0 solution? Also note, that chances are your implementation will be O(N^2), because there are no arrays in XPath 1.0, 2.0 or even 3.0 (though maybe there would be in 3.1). This means that an average access to an item of a sequence might well be O(N), and swap of items requires creating a new sequence -- also O(N), or even O(N^2)...

Comment: >I am trying to write a heap sort algorithm using XSLT I wonder if that's a sensible thing to do? Like many algorithms found in the computer science literature, written descriptions of this algorithm are generally procedural. When you are using a functional programming language, it's often appropriate to rethink the algorithms you are using, and express what you want to achieve declaratively. In this case, that means using xsl:sort. The very notion of a "heap" is alien to XSLT.

Comment: This is for my Curriculum exercise and we are looking to create a sorting function using Heap sort algorithm.I am trying to create something like this in XSLT http://fatalweb.com/question/heapsort-algorithm-indexed-1-through-n-and-actual-code-has-to-be-from-0-to-n-1-11131193.html

Comment: This is for my Curriculum exercise and we are looking to create a sorting function using Heap sort algorithm.I am trying to create something like this in XSLT http://fatalweb.com/question/heapsort-algorithm-indexed-1-through-n-and-actual-code-has-to-be-from-0-to-n-1-11131193.html

Comment: @user1834405, I doubt very much that the excercise mandated using XSLT as the programming language. Any implementation of the HeapSort algorithm in XSLT would be most likely O(N^2) or even O(N^3). The reason is that right now there isn't an *array* datatype in XPath (even in version 3.0), and an access to an item in a sequence typically is O(N) and not the O(1) that makes arrays great. Also, as with any pure functional language, it is not possible to make a "swap in place" and after every swap you'll need to start using the *new* sequence that is created by the swap operation.

Comment: @user1834405, Your last edit is unfortunate -- now you have a non-question, that makes meaningless the work of two people that tried to answer the previous verion of your question. -1.

Answer (score 1):

**I. Here is an XSLT 2.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:sequence select="my:swap(/*/*, 3, 7)"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:function name="my:swap" as="item()*">
  <xsl:param name="pSeq" as="item()*"/>
  <xsl:param name="pPos1" as="xs:integer"/>
  <xsl:param name="pPos2" as="xs:integer"/>

  <xsl:sequence select=
   "$pSeq[position() lt $pPos1],
    $pSeq[$pPos2],
    $pSeq[position() gt $pPos1 and position() lt $pPos2],
    $pSeq[$pPos1],
    $pSeq[position() gt $pPos2]
   "/>
 </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<nums>
  <num>01</num>
  <num>02</num>
  <num>03</num>
  <num>04</num>
  <num>05</num>
  <num>06</num>
  <num>07</num>
  <num>08</num>
  <num>09</num>
  <num>10</num>
</nums>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<num>01</num>
<num>02</num>
<num>07</num>
<num>04</num>
<num>05</num>
<num>06</num>
<num>03</num>
<num>08</num>
<num>09</num>
<num>10</num>
```

---

**II. Equivalent XSLT 1.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:call-template name="swap">
   <xsl:with-param name="pSeq" select="/*/*"/>
   <xsl:with-param name="pPos1" select="3"/>
   <xsl:with-param name="pPos2" select="7"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="swap">
  <xsl:param name="pSeq"/>
  <xsl:param name="pPos1"/>
  <xsl:param name="pPos2"/>

  <xsl:copy-of select="$pSeq[$pPos1 > position()]"/>
  <xsl:copy-of select="$pSeq[$pPos2]"/>
  <xsl:copy-of select="$pSeq[position() > $pPos1 and $pPos2 > position()]"/>
  <xsl:copy-of select="$pSeq[$pPos1]"/>
  <xsl:copy-of select="$pSeq[position() > $pPos2]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the same XML document (above), the same correct result is produced**:

```
<num>01</num>
<num>02</num>
<num>07</num>
<num>04</num>
<num>05</num>
<num>06</num>
<num>03</num>
<num>08</num>
<num>09</num>
<num>10</num>
```

Comment: Thanks for the responses, i tried running xslt but somehow is not giving the result wanted. I want to use the std heapsort algorithm functions BuildHeap and Heapify.Where Buildheap is used for iterating through each items and make call to Heapify.Heapify will compare the current element (let it be index i) with 2i th element and 2i +1 .If any case 2i or 2i +1 is larger than ith then will replace the  ith with largest element and will make call to heapify again. In sample provided me i am not able to replace the elements.so I really looking forward to the help in replacing the elements.

Comment: @user1834405, Regardless of the problems you have to re-write this solution into your code, this question is fully answered. As for your attempt to implement heap sort using XSLT 2.0, I believe this would result in a very inefficient (O(N^2) or even O(N^3)) implementation, because there is no *array* type in XPath (even in XPath 3.0) and obtaining `$vSeq[$n]` typically would be O(N). I know well the heap-sort algorithm and this is one algorithm that is most inappropriate for XSLT implementation.

Comment: @user1834405, I think you are not aware that XSLT is a functional language and due to this it is impossible to perform "swap in place". This means that the swap produces a *new* sequence, which you must take and use. I believe that this misunderstanding is the main cause of your problems.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tweak of Dimitre's XSLT 2.0 solution. It is not efficient at scale, but some might prefer the improved readability

Modify the xsl:sequence instruction to...

```
  <xsl:sequence select="
    for $i in $pSeq,
        $p in index-of( $pSeq, $i) return
      $pSeq[
           if ($p eq $pPos1) then
               $pPos2
           else if ($p eq $pPos2) then
               $pPos1
           else
               $p]" />
   </xsl:function>
```

### Caveat:

For this to work, it requires $pSeq to be comprised entirely of unique items. It will not work if the sequence contains duplicate nodes or same-value atomic items. But looking at the question context, this is probably a safe assumption.

### Update:

Here is a better one.

```
  <xsl:sequence select="
    for $p in 1 to count($pSeq) return
      $pSeq[
           if ($p eq $pPos1) then
               $pPos2
           else if ($p eq $pPos2) then
               $pPos1
           else
               $p]" />
   </xsl:function>
```

---

### Update # 2

The solutions given to the OP's question, by both Dimitre and myself are both absolutely correct. The OP has replied that his answer *somehow is not giving the result wanted?* but has been unable to articulate any relevant details in relation to in what this result wrong. It's difficult to help posters who are reluctant to clarify, so I think the most helpful thing I can do here is to provide a complete solution to the HeapSort that the OP is trying to develop.

As stated by others, in a real-world environment, one would just use xsl:sort. In fact, even as an academic question, its not a good academic question because it's necessary distance from a real-world solution is likely to mis-inform and confuse students. Never-the-less, I present to you, an XSLT 2.0 implementation of Heapsort (using the algorithm on this [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort)).

### (Update Note)

Please see Dimitre's comments in relation to efficiency. Any custom built sorting is going to hopelessly inefficient compared to the native sort (xsl:sort). There is really no good reason to do this, unless forced to do so as an academic exercise.

As the OP has forgotten to supply a Use Case, I will supply one here.

**Use Case 1:**

**With this input...**

```
<t>6 5 3 1 8 7 2 4</t>
```

**The goal is to sort the integers and produce this output...**

```
<t>
   <n>1</n>
   <n>2</n>
   <n>3</n>
   <n>4</n>
   <n>5</n>
   <n>6</n>
   <n>7</n>
   <n>8</n>
</t>
```

**This XSLT 2.0 style-sheet will sort an array of integers using the Heap sort algorithm...**

### (Update Note)

This stylesheet has an error in it. I am in the process of correcting it.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
  xmlns:so="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13445906"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xsl xs fn so">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each select="so:heapsort( for $x in tokenize(.,' ') return xs:integer($x))">
      <n><xsl:value-of select="." /></n>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:copy>   
</xsl:template>

<xsl:function name="so:heapsort" as="xs:integer*">
  <xsl:param name="a" as="xs:integer*" />
  <xsl:sequence select="so:one-heapsort( so:heapify( $a, count($a) idiv 2), count($a))" />
</xsl:function>

<xsl:function name="so:one-heapsort" as="xs:integer*">
  <xsl:param name="a" as="xs:integer*" />
  <xsl:param name="end" as="xs:integer" />
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$end gt 0">
      <xsl:sequence select="so:one-heapsort(
        so:siftDown( so:swap( $a, 1, $end), 1, $end - 1),
        $end - 1)" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:sequence select="$a" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:function name="so:heapify" as="xs:integer*">
  <xsl:param name="a" as="xs:integer*" />
  <xsl:param name="start" as="xs:integer" />
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$start gt 0">
      <xsl:sequence select="so:heapify(
        so:siftDown( $a, $start, count($a)),
        $start - 1)" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:sequence select="$a" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:function name="so:siftDown" as="xs:integer*">
  <xsl:param name="a" as="xs:integer*" />
  <xsl:param name="start" as="xs:integer" />
  <xsl:param name="end" as="xs:integer" />

  <xsl:sequence select="
    subsequence( $a, 1, $start - 1),
    so:one-siftDown( subsequence( $a, $start, $end - $start + 1), 1),
    subsequence( $a, $end+1, count($a)-$end)
    " />
</xsl:function>

<xsl:function name="so:swap" as="xs:integer*">
  <xsl:param name="a" as="xs:integer*" />
  <xsl:param name="x" as="xs:integer" />
  <xsl:param name="y" as="xs:integer" />

  <xsl:sequence select="
    for $p in 1 to count($a) return $a[
        if ($p eq $x) then $y
        else if ($p eq $y) then $x
        else $p]" />
</xsl:function>

<xsl:function name="so:one-siftDown" as="xs:integer*">
  <xsl:param name="a" as="xs:integer*" />
  <xsl:param name="root" as="xs:integer" />

  <xsl:variable name="left-child" select="$root * 2" as="xs:integer" />
  <xsl:variable name="right-child" select="$left-child + 1" as="xs:integer" />
  <xsl:variable name="palette" select="($a[$root], $a[$left-child], $a[$right-child])" />
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="exists( $palette)">
      <xsl:variable name="max-pos" select="index-of($palette,max($palette))[1]" />
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="($left-child le count($a)) and ($max-pos eq 2)">
          <xsl:sequence select="so:one-siftDown(
            so:swap( $a, $root, $left-child),
            $left-child)" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="($right-child le count($a)) and ($max-pos eq 3)">
          <xsl:sequence select="so:one-siftDown(
            so:swap( $a, $root, $right-child),
            $right-child)" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:sequence select="$a" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:sequence select="$a" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:function>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

## NOTES

1. The swap() function is the swap function that the OP has asked for in the question, except that it is specialized to integers, not items.
2. You could use Dimitre's implementation of swap or mine. I would be interested to know the OP's opinion on which is more readable . There is even a third way -- You could combine subsequence() and the concatination operator (`,`) .
3. As an academic discussion point, this style-sheet would be very much simpler in XSLT 3.0 Working Draft 10 July 2012, because the algorithm is highly amenable to the new [fn:fold-left() function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-fold-left). If the question was generalised to sort any-thing by any function, this task would be a great show-case for the draft XSLT 3.0. IMHO, show-case tasks for the draft XSLT 3.0 are disconcertingly scarce. I've been trying to [collect them](http://seanbdurkin.id.au/pascaliburnus2/archives/10).

Comment: Thanks for the responses, i tried running xslt but somehow is not giving the result wanted. I want to use the std heapsort algorithm functions BuildHeap and Heapify.Where Buildheap is used for iterating through each items and make call to Heapify.Heapify will compare the current element (let it be index i) with 2i th element and 2i +1 .If any case 2i or 2i +1 is larger than ith then will replace the  ith with largest element and will make call to heapify again. In sample provided me i am not able to replace the elements.

Comment: You need to be more specific than just saying _somehow is not giving the result wanted_ . In what way is it wrong?

Comment: As a matter of curiosity, why are you implementing a custom sort function? What is wrong with the native sort?

Comment: Also why have you tagged the question both 1.0 and 2.0? Do you really need solutions for both? For the optimal outcome, please specify your XSLT version and XSLT vendor/processor. Also could you specify a good use case. A use case will include a sample input document and your expected output document.

Comment: This is for my Curriculum exercise and we are looking to create a sorting function using Heap sort algorithm.So we wont be able to use any sort built in fuctions available in XSLT.We must implement the BuildHeap and Heapify methods int the below url in XSLT http://fatalweb.com/question/heapsort-algorithm-indexed-1-through-n-and-actual-code-has-to-be-from-0-to-n-1-11131193.html

Comment: Ah well, that kind of awkward. Homework questions are against the spirit of StackOverflow, and it's kind of unfair to the other students.

Comment: Well after doing some ['homework'](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated) on [tag:homework], your question is probably ok, so I will have an attempt at it.

Comment: i am trying to get a help for the difficulties am facing in the Implementation, not trying get someone does the job for me. That what i explained swapping difficulties with the existing variables in XSLT

Comment: @user1834405 See updated solution.

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin, Why didn't you warn the OP that a HeapSort implementation in XSLT is hopelessly inefficient? Maybe you yourself are not aware of this? If there is one algorithm that is *most* unsuitable to be implemented in XSLT, that is HeapSort!

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin, I tested your solution, with 8000 items it takes 175 seconds and uses 3426MB (3.5GB) RAM. For 800 items it only takes 2 seconds -- which probably means my guess about O(N^3) is correct, and uses only 2.5GB of RAM. More seriously,the result for 8000 items is incorrect -- I get fragments like this:    `<n>7</n>
   <n>8</n>
   <n>7</n>
   <n>7</n>
   <n>8</n>
   <n>7</n>
   <n>7</n>
   <n>8</n>
   <n>7</n>
   <n>7</n>
   <n>7</n>
   <n>7</n>
   <n>8</n>
   <n>7</n>
   <n>8</n>
   <n>7</n>
   <n>8</n>
   <n>7</n>
   <n>7</n>
   <n>8</n>
   <n>7</n>`

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin: Even for 80 items the result still contains unsorted fragments, like:    `<n>5</n>
   <n>5</n>
   <n>8</n>
   <n>5</n>
   <n>5</n>
   <n>5</n>
   <n>6</n>
   <n>5</n>
   <n>5</n>
   <n>5</n>
   <n>5</n>
   <n>5</n>
   <n>8</n>
   <n>7</n>
   <n>6</n>
   <n>7</n>
   <n>6</n>
   <n>6</n>
   <n>6</n>
   <n>8</n>
   <n>6</n>
   <n>6</n>
   <n>6</n>
   <n>6</n>
   <n>6</n>
   <n>7</n>
   <n>7</n>
   <n>8</n>
   <n>7</n>`

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Yes, I agree that HeapSort in XSLT is horribly inefficient. I did try to explain why xsl:sort would be much better, but perhaps my articulation could have been better. I will update my answer accordingly. As for the error - I will investigate and correct. Thankyou for bringing it to my attention.

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin, It isn't only about efficiency -- the whole idea of *heap sort* is that it can be done *in place* and doesn't need a single byte of additional space -- to implement this in XSLT is to make a cartoon of the main idea of this algorithm.

Comment: Yes. It's very strange that this would be set as a curriculum exercise. I wonder if there is some missing relevant information that should have been posted by the OP? Or maybe it is just as simple as a lack of quality in the provided educational service?

Comment: Hmm.. Just saw the question edit. Puzzling ...

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Voting to close. Too much effort spent on what is now a non-question.

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin, Yes, so did I, and -1 too.